# Django dynamic field in the admin panel one to many

Tags: python, django, postgresql

There are related tables: equipment and orders. Can I fill in an array of equipment and its quantity in the admin panel when adding a new entity to the orders table?

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Order(models.Model):
    # equipment = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255))
```

Comment: StackOverflow is an English only site

Comment: Something like a basket in an online store

Comment: You may also try https://ru.stackoverflow.com if you find Russian easier.

Comment: Maybe need to redefine change_form.html , where jquery will create entries in the intermediate table